# I don't know how to implement this function in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

Many thanks for the contributions, with all of them I have made a mix and I have solved it in part but I have only one thing left ...
I have done this function, which adds num_tweets, which adds the "words" when they are 1, but when it matches and should + 1, the variable is undefined and I do not understand the reason ..
The problem had to do this from these JSON

```
{
        "numtweets" : 1,
        "dic_words" : {
                "word1" : 1,
                "word2" : 1,
                "word3" : 1,
                "word4" : 1,
                "word5" : 1,
                "word6" : 1,
                "word7" : 1
        }
}

{
        "numtweets" : 1,
        "dic_words" : {
                "word1" : 1,
                "word2" : 1,
                "word9" : 1
        }
}

{
        "numtweets" : 1,
        "dic_words" : {
                "word1" : 1,
                "word3" : 1,
                "word10" : 1
        }
}
```

I would like that in the end I return a json only adding all fields, add contweets, but also the word that matches in this case would come out like this...

```
{
            "numtweets" : 3, //add numtweets
            "dic_words" : {
                    "word1" : 3, //num_occurs word1 in array
                    "word2" : 2, //num_occurs word2 in array
                    "word3" : 2, //num_occurs word3 in array
                    "word4" : 1,  //num_occurs word3 in array
                    "word5" : 1,
                    "word6" : 1,
                    "word7" : 1,
                    "word9" : 1,
                    "word10" : 1
            }
    }
```

my function is ...

```
var r =  function(key, values) {
    result = { "numtweets" : 0,
          "dic_words" : {}
        };
      //   print("  entrada: " + tojson(values));
   for (var idx = 0; idx < values.length; idx++) {
     result.numtweets += values[idx].numtweets;
   //  print("  json: " + tojson(values[idx].dic_words));
        for (paraula in values[idx].dic_words) {
            if(values[idx].dic_words.hasOwnProperty(paraula)) {
            if(values[idx].dic_words[paraula]) {
                           result.dic_words[paraula] = result.dic_words[paraula] + values[idx].dic_words[paraula]; //IS these **part result.dic_words[paraula]** is ***undefined***
           }
            else 
               result.dic_words[paraula] = 1; /^* this part is correct, and if the word appers one only it appears ocurrs

               }
        }   
        }
return result;
};
```

The output is

```
{
                "numtweets" : 3, //add numtweets
                "dic_words" : {
                        **"word1" : NaN, //num_occurs word1 in array MUST BE 3
                        "word2" : NaN, //num_occurs word2 in array MUST BE 2
                        "word3" : NaN, //num_occurs word3 in array MUST BE 2**
                        "word4" : 1,  //num_occurs word3 in array
                        "word5" : 1,
                        "word6" : 1,
                        "word7" : 1,
                        "word9" : 1,
                        "word10" : 1
                }
        }
```

Please any suggestions or help will be welcome...

Comment: What is the question then? You've provided code in much simpler cases, but not the one that you've tried to apply here

Comment: that is unfortunate.

Comment: Sorry, I try all then answers that they give me, put  the codes, in mongodb, but all the attempts, didn't work it. I don't know the reason, because I'm a beginner in Javascript and mongodb, for this reason I try other other opcions, and the change, it works partially... but not ok 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this function:

```js
function getSummary(data) {
    return data.reduce(function (acc, o) {
        return {
            numtweets: acc.numtweets + (+o.numtweets || 0),
            dic_words: Object.keys(o.dic_words || {}).reduce(function (words, word) {
                words[word] = (words[word] || 0) + o.dic_words[word];
                return words;
            }, acc.dic_words)
        };
    }, { numtweets: 0, dic_words: {} });
}

// Sample data
var data = [{
    "numtweets" : 1,
    "dic_words" : { "word1" : 1, "word2" : 1, "word3" : 1, "word4" : 1, 
                    "word5" : 1, "word6" : 1, "word7" : 1 }
}, {
    "numtweets" : 1,
    "dic_words" : { "word1" : 1, "word2" : 1, "word9" : 1 }
}, {
    "numtweets" : 1,
    "dic_words" : { "word1" : 1, "word3" : 1, "word10" : 1 }
}, { // empty object added to test algorithm will survive and ignore this...
}];

console.log(getSummary(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thans but it does a mistake in mongodb                      <br> var r = function (key,countObjVals) {
...      return countObjVals.reduce( (acc, o) => ({
...         numtweets: acc.numtweets + o.numtweets,
...         dic_words: Object.keys(o.dic_words).reduce( (words, word) =>
...             (words[word] = (words[word] || 0) + o.dic_words[word], words)
...         , acc.dic_words )
...     }), { numtweets: 0, dic_words: {} } );
...     }
2017-04-29T15:51:47.747+0200 SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

Comment: That means your programming environment does not support ES6. I have updated my answer. Now it has an ES5 version of the code.

Comment: Thanks for all with the 4 solutions I solved in part, but I still have a mistake

I changed the question, with the error

Comment: Why don't you use the code I provided? Also make sure your original data has numbers, not strings with numbers?

Comment: I proved the original code, but It doesn't work, I tried again this afternoon the original code again, maybe I put some mistake...

Comment: The snippet I posted wotks when I run it. Does the snippet work when you run it?

Comment: I put your code, into mongodb, (for mapreduce) and it doesn't work->**""exception: TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object near 's: Object.keys(o.dic_words).reduce(functi' line 6",**   var r = function (key,CountObjVal) {
return CountObjVal.reduce(function (acc, o) {
      return {
          numtweets: acc.numtweets + o.numtweets,
          dic_words: Object.keys(o.dic_words).reduce(function (words, word) {
              words[word] = (words[word] || 0) + o.dic_words[word];
              return words;
          }, acc.dic_words)
      };
  }, { numtweets: 0, dic_words: {} });
};

Comment: The code is the same as you put me, changing the variable data by CountObjVal, and the input of the function that is with two variables, but the JSON array is CountObjVal

Comment: Did you read what the error said? It means that `o.dic_words` is not an object. Yet in your question you told us you data is an array of objects that have a `dic_words` property, which is an object. So not all objects have `doc_words`?

Comment: Anyway, I updated my answer with some additional `( ...... || 0)` and `( ...... || {})` to ignore cases where `numtweets` or `dic_words` is not defined in your source data. Please try it on your data.

Comment: thanks with this correction it looks good! Sorry by my mistakes, but I'm a very very beginner in javascript

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
        "numtweets" : 1,
        "dic_words" : {
                "word1" : 1,
                "word2" : 1,
                "word3" : 1,
                "word4" : 1,
                "word5" : 1,
                "word6" : 1,
                "word7" : 1
        }
},
{
        "numtweets" : 1,
        "dic_words" : {
                "word1" : 1,
                "word2" : 1,
                "word9" : 1
        }
},

{
        "numtweets" : 1,
        "dic_words" : {
                "word1" : 1,
                "word3" : 1,
                "word10" : 1
        }
}];


function processData(input) {
  var result = {numtweets: 0, dic_words:{}};
  
  input.forEach(function(item){
     result['numtweets'] += item['numtweets'];
     for(var i in  item['dic_words']) {
        result['dic_words'][i] = (result['dic_words'][i]) ? result['dic_words'][i]+item['dic_words'][i] : item['dic_words'][i];
     }
  })
  return result;
}


console.log(processData(data))
```

Comment: With the 4 solutions I solved in part, but I still have a mistake

I changed the question, with the error, can you look if you know the answer please

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var arr = [
      {
          "numtweets": 1,
          "dic_words": {
              "word1": 1,
              "word2": 1,
              "word3": 1,
              "word4": 1,
              "word5": 1,
              "word6": 1,
              "word7": 1
          }
      },
    
      {
          "numtweets": 1,
          "dic_words": {
              "word1": 1,
              "word2": 1,
              "word9": 1
          }
      },
    
      {
          "numtweets": 1,
          "dic_words": {
              "word1": 1,
              "word3": 1,
              "word10": 1
          }
      }
    ]
    
    var newObj = { numtweets: 0, dic_words: {} };
    
    arr.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
    
        newObj.numtweets += item.numtweets;
    
        for (var prop in item.dic_words) {
            if (!newObj.dic_words[prop]) { newObj.dic_words[prop] = 0 };
            newObj.dic_words[prop] +=  item.dic_words[prop];
        }
    
    })
    
    console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method with ES6 Arrow function.**

**DEMO**

```js
var CountObjVal = [{
        "numtweets" : 1,
        "dic_words" : {
                "word1" : 1,
                "word2" : 1,
                "word3" : 1,
                "word4" : 1,
                "word5" : 1,
                "word6" : 1,
                "word7" : 1
        }
},
{
        "numtweets" : 1,
        "dic_words" : {
                "word1" : 1,
                "word2" : 1,
                "word9" : 1
        }
},
{
        "numtweets" : 1,
        "dic_words" : {
                "word1" : 1,
                "word3" : 1,
                "word10" : 1
        }
}];

var r = function (countObjVals) { 
  var obj = {numtweets: 0, dic_words: {}}; 
  CountObjVal.map(elem => Object.keys(elem.dic_words).map(item => obj.dic_words[item] = 0)); 
  for (var i in CountObjVal) { 
    obj.numtweets += CountObjVal[i].numtweets;          
    Object.keys(CountObjVal[i].dic_words).map(item => obj.dic_words[item] += CountObjVal[i].dic_words[item]); 
  } 
  return obj; 
};

console.log(r(CountObjVal));
```

Comment: Thanks but it give a compilate error. I put this (I try to make a mapreduce), but it want this error                                                                                       var r = function (key, countObjVals) {
var obj = {numtweets: 0, dic_words: {}};
CountObjVal.map(elem => Object.keys(elem.dic_words).map(item => obj.dic_words[item] = 0));
 for (var i in CountObjVal) {
 obj.numtweets += CountObjVal[i].numtweets;
 Object.keys(CountObjVal[i].dic_words).map(item => obj.dic_words[item] += CountObjVal[i].dic_words[item]);
 }
 return obj;
 }
SyntaxError:Unexpected token >

Comment: @Miki I updated my answer as per your changes in the comment. please check i hope it will meet your expectations.

Comment: With the 4 solutions I solved in part, but I still have a mistake

I changed the question, with the error, can you look if you know the answer please